Finding the gradient direction from a derivative image
I am working on a task with reconstructing an image from its derivative image on only one direction.
Currently I managed to do this on a derivative image which was taken on X direction, by integrating it on X direction again. This works fine because I already know the derivative is on X direction and I created a horizontal 1D integral filter.

Now let's say the derivative image on X is rotated by +30 degrees. I still need to reconstruct the image but my initial approach only works when the derivative direction is on X.

My first idea was to:

Find out the gradient direction/angle (in this case, 30 degrees)
Rotate the derivative image so that the gradient direction is 0
Apply initial approach
Rotate reconstructed image back

But I couldn't figure out how to find the gradient direction. It is quite apparent in frequency domain but I'd like to avoid having to do FFT.

why would you like to avoid an FFT? It seems you have a solution, but don't want to do that. Since the same reasons you don't want to do an FFT apply elsewhere, we could be designing alternatives that you then also don't want to use, because we don't know your reasons. So, what's the reason you're precluding an FFT-based solution, exactly?

@MarcusMüller Because the way I managed to get the direction in frequency domain (basically trying to find the DC component) wasn't quite reliable for my actual case. I was just wondering if there was a way to do this in spatial domain I haven't thought of to see if there's a more straight-forward solution :-)
